# Macbook Pro VBox Kali Linux Wifi Not Working

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox

I recently installed Kali on VBox and set my network settings in VBox to Bridged Adapter which seemed to allow wifi to work for 1-2 days. Now, I am unable to connect to the internet at all, and can't use sudo in terminal to update any drivers/software on the OS. My Mac also doesn't allow ethernet as it only has USB-C ports. Considering that the wifi was working for a period of time, what should I do?

Comment: Did you in any way reconfigure the network on the host machine?

Comment: I switched wifi networks as I moved locations from my home to another place. Does that pose a problem of some sort?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0):

Bridging with wifi does not work with some technologies of WiFi/some methods of WiFi authentication.

Use a NAT device instead of a bridge configuration